# Android Nested Recycler View

Tags: android, nested, android-recyclerview

I want to add a recycler view inside a recycler view, as per android docs and many posts it is not suggested by google to do so, Is there any work around to do this ?? 
[click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mFz8.png)

```
 Note- Items inside the container are scrollable. For eg.Top_category is one list,Items under Top_category is another list
```

Comment: There is nothing in that screenshot that requires a nested `RecyclerView`. I do not know why you would have *any* `RecyclerView` there. That looks like a vertical `LinearLayout`, wrapped in a `ScrollView`, where the `LinearLayout` holds 8 cards plus the banner at the top. What are you expecting to gain by using a `RecyclerView` for any of this?

Comment: The items under the header are scrollable, say for eg. top category has girls guys ,etc more than 4 items which the user cant see, if he doesnt scroll.

Comment: OK. I think there are better options for handling this sort of nested scrolling than there used to be, but I do not know the details. Personally, I avoid UIs like this, as they seem destined to cause user confusion, as users try to scroll one thing (e.g., the whole panel) and wind up scrolling something else (e.g., one of your sub-lists) instead.

Comment: What are the other options to handle this ?? and yes i agree this UI will create a confusion, but the inner list will have a scroll bar, if the user doesnt use this scrollbar, the inner list cannot be scrolled.

Comment: "but the inner list will have a scroll bar, if the user doesnt use this scrollbar, the inner list cannot be scrolled" -- that seems worse yet. Users are not used to having to use scrollbars on mobile devices, and so they will not realize that the sub-lists are scrollable. "What are the other options to handle this ?" -- do not put it all in one vertical list. For example, use a `ViewPager`, with one sub-list per page, so vertical swipes scroll the current sub-list, and horizontal swipes switch between sub-lists.